# Serving a HTTP request response as a dialog response - Composer Framework

Tags: bot-framework-composer

We are developing a chatbot to handle internal and external processes for a local authority. We are trying to display contact information for a particular service from our api endpoint. The HTTP request is successful and delivers, in part, exactly what we want but there's still some unnecessary noise we can't exclude.

**We specifically just want the text out of the response ("Response").**

Logically, it was thought all we need to do is drill down into ${dialog.api_response.content.Response} but that fails the HTTP request and ${x.content} returns successful but includes Tags, response and the fields within [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su2Du.jpg).

Is there something simple we've missed using composer to access what we're after or do we need to change the way our endpoint is responding [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLsAC.jpg)? Unfortunately the MS documentation for FrwrkComp is lacking to say the very least.

n.b. The response is currently set up as a (syntactically) SSML response, this is just a test case using an existing resource.

[Response in the Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su2Du.jpg)
[Snippet from FwrkComp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLsAC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the first thing I tried just syntactically correct. For the case of the code given it was as simple as:

${dialog.api_response.content[0].Response}